# Download website and make it searchable

Tags: search, wget, html

Is there a software (apart from the browser) that takes multiple pages that were downloaded with `wget`, displays them and - the most important feature - offers a fast full text search as HTML (not plain text with tags like with grep)?  Should be easy to install/setup.

Comment: "DISPLAY" as in show the actual content of the page or the page itself as the website does? If the latter: no, there is no easy method.

Comment: html pages are simple text files. Just use `grep` to search through all the files in the root folder of the mirrored web page.

Comment: Yes you could use `grep` @falconer - e.g. `grep -d recurse 'SEARCH-TERM' /PATH/TO/FOLDER/WITH/WEBPAGE-FILES`, but it would appear in the HTML format of the page - e.g. `</script><script src="Downloading%20an%20Entire%20Web%20Site%20with%20wget%20%7C%20Linux%20Journal_files/all.js#xfbml=1&amp;appId=406458029406839" id="facebook-jssdk"></script><script id="bug.surrogate.1">`

Comment: Yes. But the purpose of searching is finding. (Or not?) So after the relevant page is found you can open it in the browser.

Comment: I'd like to display the relevant pages in a browser, not look at the HTML code. Clarified my question.

Answer (score 2):

For ***mirroring a website*** I like to use `httrack` rather than `wget` with *recursive retrieval options*.

**Description**: [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com) saves websites to your computer (Offline browser).

HTTrack is an *offline browser utility*, allowing you to download a World Wide website from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all
 directories, getting html, images, and other files from the server to your computer.

HTTrack *arranges the original site's relative link-structure*. Simply open a page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and *you can browse the
 site from link to link*, as if you were viewing it online. HTTrack can also update an existing mirrored site, and resume interrupted downloads. HTTrack
 is fully configurable, and has an integrated help system.

**To install** in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install httrack
```

Comment: Thanks for think link. Seems like HTTrack is just a nice GUI around wget. However, I'm more concerned with finding contents of the downloaded pages.

Comment: You can usually get a better result for downlaoding a webpage by using `wget` - it just depends on what options you use. http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget

Comment: @chiborg, I can't if `httrack` is or not a front-end to `wget`... but yeah for Window's they've got a good GUI and goes by WinHTTrack... sorry that I didn't get your question right..

Comment: @wilf, thanks for the link... really helpful...

Comment: Don't mind, ajThapa :-)

Comment: not at all... really meant that... _--convert-links_ might be one of the things I was missing...

Answer (score 1):

After you properly mirrored your website with `wget` or anything else just cd into the downloaded webpages root directory and run this:

```
find . -iname "*.htm*" -exec grep -l "WHAT_YOU_ARE_SEARCHING_GOES_HERE" {} + | xargs -d "\n" firefox
```

Then firefox will open all the pages which contains your search.

(Or a little bit more if your search term is present only in the webpage's HTML tags. If this is a problem for you, then it can also be solved by another pipe, which filters out the HTML tags.)

Comment: To do this, you will have to use wget with the `--html-extension` option, otherwise it won't search all the pages, as they do not always have .html extensions... Good answer though. The only other text files `grep` would search would likely be CSS or JavaScript files, but it would not find much there either, especially many webpages inline those in the web page anyway.

Comment: @wilf is right with the --html-extension for wget. (or for newer wget it is --adjust-extension) Thanks wilf. I don't know whether we should search inside css or javascript files? Normally a website shouldn't store viewable texts there.

Comment: Not really, they usually just control formatting. Your command might also not work for `.HTML`... :-)

Comment: That's right again. :) Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use grep, but pipe the output into a webpage, so that it is understandable as *most* of the tags would be removed, for example:

```
grep -d recurse 'SEARCH-TERM' /PATH/TO/FOLDER/WITH/WEBPAGE-FILES > OUTPUT.html
```

This would remove most of the tags and stuff, though it would be cropped to indidvidual lines, so you could use the `-C` option to show some of the context of the search result.:

```
grep -d recurse -C 5 'SEARCH-TERM' /PATH/TO/FOLDER/WITH/WEBPAGE-FILES > OUTPUT.html
```

where 5 is the number of lines in each direction to give the search result more context.

For more options, see `man grep`

<sub>Really, a web browser is the best tool to search a web page - I can't think of much else</sub>

Oh, and to make sure that you search only webpages (with the extension .htm or .html):

```
find . -name "*.htm*" -exec grep -d recurse -C 5 'SEARCH-TERM' /PATH/TO/FOLDER/WITH/WEBPAGE-FILES > OUTPUT.html
```

---

Also, to improve any downloading of webpages / websites with `wget`, look [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget).