# Downloading a complete webpage

Tags: 14.04, downloads, webapps, websites

How can I ***download*** a ***complete webpage*** through ***terminal***. Providing address of a webpage should automatically indicate the sub pages related to it.
Are there any GUI alternatives?

Comment: Take a look here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155423/possible-to-download-these-webpages-as-a-book. you can also install and use `httrack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simple way I know of: `wget -r URL_OF_PAGE`. Default recursion depth is 5. More info can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html).

Related questions on AU: [download-website-and-make-it-searchable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388328/download-website-and-make-it-searchable/388342#388342)

Comment: Can the depth level be increased? And where are the files saved after they are downloaded?

Comment: the depth level can easily be increased. Files are saved where you ran the command.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the `--mirror` switch for this kind of job.

`wget -m URL_OF_PAGE`

here is what `man wget` says about it:

```
-m
--mirror
Turn on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings.  It is currently equivalent to -r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing.
```